# How to pass list parameter oracle procedure using hibernate and java

Tags: hibernate

I need to pass class list like List myList . And I tried

In java:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("registerTest")
                    .setParameter("excList", myList);

            System.out.println(" SUCCESS " +query.executeUpdate());
```

In oracle :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE inc_list IS OBJECT (field1 int, field2 int); 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FUNC_MYFUNC(INC_LIST IN inc_list) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS acc_bal NUMBER(11,2);
   BEGIN 
        acc_bal:=1;
       RETURN acc_bal;
    END;
```

to check parameter send or not. But gives error

```
{call FUNC_MYFUNC(?)}
32559 [http-bio-9090-exec-10] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 6550, SQLState: 65000
32559 [http-bio-9090-exec-10] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FUNC_MYFUNC'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Error inc exc : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to use next call:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("registerTest")
                    .setParameterList("excList", myList);
```